# Increasing odds of using pre-built binaries with conan

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

Coming from using the conan package manager via cmake on my M1 Mac mini where conan would usually be able to download and rely on pre-built binaries given the `--build=missing` option, I was disappointed that on a docker container built on `debian:sid` with standard compilation tools such as the gcc toolchain enabled, every package was being built from source, thus taking extremely long to complete.

How does one ensure or encourage that conan sees a standard or common build environment such that one's chances of using pre-built packages are maximized?

Comment: a quick glance through conan center seems that packages are available for most versions of gcc. Which architecture are you using? Which libraries are you using? What's the output of `conan profile show default`?

Comment: It's gcc-12 defaulted to by `debian:sid`.

Comment: Conan centre doesn't support gcc 12 yet https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/docs/supported_platforms_and_configurations.md

Comment: I do not recommend using your own Docker image, if you want to consume pre-built packages from Conan Center. Instead, use the official conanio/gcc12-ubuntu16.04:latest. More information: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools/tree/master/modern (GCC12 is not listed on README but is already available on hub.docker)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alan Birtles and @uilianries 's comments, here's what worked for me.

First, one needs a good idea of the heaviest packages one needs. Let's take the example of `boost/1.80` whose libraries require a considerable time to build. Next, scan through the list of available binary packages, e.g., `boost/1.80.0:0c77626be2b1f8b44c0b5609c80dd9c16c06d6af` and read its conan info, which contains the specification

```
[settings]
    arch=x86_64
    build_type=Debug
    compiler=clang
    compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
    compiler.version=12
    os=Linux
```

These are the settings one needs to provide in the `SETTINGS` spec for `conan_cmake_install()`, e.g.,

```
conan_cmake_install(
            BUILD missing
            PATH_OR_REFERENCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            REMOTE conancenter
            GENERATORS cmake
            SETTINGS compiler=clang compiler.version=12 compiler.libcxx=libstdc++ cppstd=23
    )
```

Note that relatively current compiler versions may not supported for all the packages one is interested in installing, so choosing a conservative compiler version is often the optimal choice.

Of course, `conan` must be able to *find* the specified compiler and a compatible `c++` standard library. This is greatly eased if one containerises one's compilation environment and employs the `docker` base images provided by `conan-io` such as [conanio/clang12-ubuntu16.04: clang 12](https://hub.docker.com/r/conanio/clang12-ubuntu16.04/). These images are what the binary packages are actually built against by *JFrog ConanCenter* and helps `conan` avoid the expensive build-from-sources stage.